# What are the usual methods used for collecting email information from a corporate website?

Tags: email, phishing

- What are the usual methods used for collecting email information from a corporate website, and
- What are the usual ways one can undertake to protect that data i.e. to protect its users/emails from receiving spam etc. etc.?*

Basically, what I'm asking is: When you have a website or you maintain a website, onto which, due to the nature of business, individuals have to have displayed emails "in plain sight", what are the usual methods (apart from active ones, such as spam filters) one can employ so that ... whoever those people are ... cannot collect email data, and use it for all kinds of spam & time wasting activities?

Comment: Have you seen this one? [Does e-mail address obfuscation actually work?](http://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-e-mail-address-obfuscation-actually-work)

Comment: Better on Pro Webmasters if asking about how to implement something instead of polling

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the "@" symbol is usually a tip off for crawlers.  Beyond that, basic formatting may tip them off too.  I've had good luck in the past by changing how it is displayed/formatted.  For instance, instead of test@tester.com, try "test at tester dot com"

If that isnt doable due to the nature of the website/business...then I'll have to have someone else chime in.

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling most crawlers have caught onto the "at dot" thing a decade ago.